# web.config redirect to https with 301 status code

Tags: redirect, iis, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to force redirect all http traffic to https **while returning `301` status code**.
So I have this in my Web.Release.config file.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" statusCode="301" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

and I keep getting `307` instead of `301`. How can I force it to return `301` status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" statusCode="301" redirectType="Permanent" />`

According to your code, we could find that you specify `redirectType="Permanent"`, it should return 301 status code. I try to reproduce the issue on my side, here is my config files.

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433-->
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>

      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Web.Release.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>-->
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.
  
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>-->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I could see 301 status code in Network tool when I visit my website.

[image]

> I keep getting 307 instead of 301. How can I force it to return 301 status code?

You could check your Web.config file and make sure whether you define other URL Rewrite Rules that change status code.

Comment: Any idea on where to start looking for anything that over writes this? I have no other redirection rules

Comment: strange enough, only chrome returns 307. FF and edge show 301 redirection..